# Getting the string representation from CDbCriteria

Tags: yii

Is there any way to the get the string representation of the query from [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria)? For testing and debugging purposes.

Comment: `CDbCriteria` does not aggregate enough information to construct a full query. The model class also has a significant amount of relevant information, so you would need to involve both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use logging and profiling configuring your main.php like this:

```
'components'=>array(
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                'categories'=>'system.db.CDbCommand',
                'showInFireBug'=>true,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'db'=>array(
        'enableProfiling'=>true,
        'enableParamLogging'=>true,
    ),              
),
```

Comment: Ok, if I added the lines with enableProfiling, enableParamLogging and showInFireBug (those were the only ones in my config that was missing) how do I go get the SQL? I do expect that the FireBug setting will make the SQL show in FireBug, correct?

Comment: Yes, as far as I remember.

Comment: Puigcerber, I just cannot get anything to log on my local instance on my Windows 7 machine. Where in firebug should I see this, in the Console tab? If it is not there, where should I go look? To see the sql, is it required to do something like Log.Debug($criteria) for me to see anything?

Comment: Yes, if you refresh the site with the console open, all the queries should be printed there.

Comment: @Puigcerber when you say console is it command prompt?  or yii show some window on webpage?

Comment: The browser console.

Answer (score 4):

I spend a lot amount of time for finding the answer to this question, so thought of sharing it with you guys. Hope this saves your precious time.

As mentioned by Jon above: `CDbCriteria` does not aggregate enough information to construct the full query, you have to use the model class information also on which you will put the query constraints.

As the example given in Yii docs for [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria); this is how basically you use it-

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria(); 
$criteria->compare('status',Post::STATUS_ACTIVE); 
$criteria->addInCondition('id',array(1,2,3,4,5,6)); 

$posts = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Here `Post` is the name of the model on which you execute the query condition.

So if you want to get the text representation of the query written in CDbCriteria, you have to involve the model information also i.e. Post.

This is how you can do it -

```
$model = new Post();
$query = $model->getCommandBuilder()->createFindCommand($model->getTableSchema(), $criteria)->getText();
```

When you print the value in `$query` variable it prints the raw query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer and better than changing the logging settings. The only issue with the final query is that it still contains the placeholders, such as ":productId".

Comment: This helped my a lot! I just had to add a join that it didn't seem to account for.