# Get SQL produced from CDbCriteria

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii

I have a YII CDbCriteria and want to know what SQL is produced, where do I go to get this. My CDbCriteria is a basic join on 2 tables using $criteria->with . I know this is not a lot to go on but I found some articles stating I should add a logging feature, I only want this once and then move on. Any help please?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895982/getting-the-string-representation-from-cdbcriteria

Answer (score 0):

In your main config php, uncomment the below and you can view the logs.

```
array(
    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
    ),
```