# Yii 1: CActiveDataProvider does not return all records

Tags: php, mysql, yii, cactivedataprovider

Here is my CActiveDataProvider query.

```
$startDate='2016-02-28';
$endDate='2016-03-05';
     $criteria= new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->with=array('job','job.serviceType');
        $criteria->order='t.uploaded_date DESC';
        $criteria->select='t.id,t.job_master_id,t.image_path,t.image_name,t.uploaded_date';
     $criteria->condition="SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.`image_name`,'.',-1) in ('jpg','jpeg','png','gif','JPG','PNG','GIF','JPEG') and job.trade_company_id='".Yii::app()->user->getState('TradeCompanyId')."' and job.current_assigned='".Yii::app()->user->id."'";
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('DATE(uploaded_date)', $endDate, $startDate);
```

This gives me 0 rows. but when i use same query in mysql it gives me proper result. following is same mysql query

```
SELECT `t`.`job_master_id`
FROM `media` `t`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `job_master` `job` ON ( `t`.`job_master_id` = `job`.`id` )
INNER JOIN `service_type_master` `serviceType` ON ( `job`.`service_type_id` = `serviceType`.`id` )
WHERE (
    (
        SUBSTRING_INDEX( t.`image_name` , '.' , -1 ) IN ( 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'JPG', 'PNG', 'GIF', 'JPEG')
        AND job.trade_company_id = '7' AND job.current_assigned = "14"
    )
    AND (
        DATE( uploaded_date ) BETWEEN '2016-02-28' AND '2016-03-05'
    )
)
ORDER BY `t`.`uploaded_date` DESC
```

I tried setting pagination to 1000 in CActiveDataProvider but this nothing works.

```
$dataProvider= new CActiveDataProvider($model,array('criteria'=>$criteria,'pagination' =>array('pageSize'=>1000)));
```

even i set pagination to `false` but still no result

```
$dataProvider= new CActiveDataProvider($model,array('criteria'=>$criteria,'pagination' =>false));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `Parse error` into your `$criteria->condition` (`job.current_assigned="'.Yii::app()->user->id.'""`)

Try to replace it with this string:

```
$criteria->condition="SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.`image_name`,'.',-1) in ('jpg','jpeg','png','gif','JPG','PNG','GIF','JPEG') and job.trade_company_id='".
    Yii::app()->user->getState('TradeCompanyId').
    "' and job.current_assigned='".Yii::app()->user->id."'";
```

Comment: i solved this but still no result. it returns me blank array

Comment: try to enable logging sql queries and get real query which creating by this $criteria. E.g. this answer can help you to enable query logging in Yii: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9898068/2253302